# Rubocop disable rule in AllCops

Tags: ruby, rubocop

I'm trying to disable a rule defined in AllCops - it appears that

`# rubocop:disable all`

does not ignore rules defined under AllCops, specifically TargetRubyVersion.

Is there a way to completely disable Rubocop altogether for a certain block of code?

Comment: Does Rubocop complain about `TargetRubyVersion` violations within that block of code which should be excluded?

Comment: Does this help? https://github.com/bbatsov/rubocop#enabled

Comment: @spickermann Yes, it throws the following: literal contains escape sequences incompatible with UTF-8
(Using Ruby 2.0 parser; configure using TargetRubyVersion parameter, under AllCops)

Comment: @Alfie no, that doesn't appear to affect it

Comment: Is it possible that you are affected by this [issue in Rubocop](https://github.com/whitequark/parser/issues/283)? What version of Rubocop do you use?

Comment: Yeah, that was the fix - thank you @spickermann

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It feels to me like you are affected by this [issue in Rubocop](https://github.com/whitequark/parser/issues/283). I suggest upgrading Rubocop to a newer version.